# route() not working with Route::enableFilters()

Tags: php, unit-testing, routes, laravel-4

I'm unit testing my application and I get a `NotFoundHttpException` when trying to call controller actions with `TestCase::callSecure()` and the `route()` helper.

For those tests (only a few) I have also enabled filters with `Route::enableFilters`.

My filters.php:

```
App::before(
    function ($request) {
        // force ssl
        if (!$request->isSecure())
        {
            return Redirect::secure($request->getRequestUri());
        }
    }
);

// some authentication
Route::filter('auth.api', 'Authentication');
```

My routes.php:

```
Route::post('login', array('as' => 'login', 'uses' => 'AuthenticationController@login'));
Route::post('register', array('as' => 'register', 'uses' => 'AuthenticationController@register'));
```

Example Test where i get the exception:

```
$credentials = [
    // ...
];

$response = $this->callSecure('POST', route('login'), $credentials);
```

When i call those actions by their path, it works fine.

```
$credentials = [
    // ...
];

$response = $this->callSecure('POST', '/login', $credentials);
```

Is this intended or a bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [route()](http://laravel.com/docs/helpers#urls) helper will generate a [URL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_resource_locator) (including the relevant protocol, i.e. http/s) for the given named route. In your case, it'll return something like:

> https://example.com/login

Which isn't what you want. This is useful when you want to perform a redirect, for example:

```
Redirect::route('login');
```

So what you're doing in your last example, is the correct way to be doing what you want; as you don't want to pass the full URL as a parameter to your callSecure() function.

```
$response = $this->callSecure('POST', '/login', $credentials);
```

And as dave has mentioned, you can generate a relative URL by using URL::route and pass an `$absolute` parameter which defaults to `true`. For example, when using named routes you can use the following:

```
$route = URL::route('profile', array(), false);
```

Which will generate a relative URL like `/profile`

Answer (score 0):

The `route()` helper does not create relative URLs, which is what you really want.

To generate a relative URL, you can use `URL::route` as it allows you to pass a `$absolute` parameter which defaults to true. So to get your relative url using a named route, you could do

```
$credentials = [
// ...
];
$route = URL::route('login', array(), false);
$response = $this->callSecure('POST', $route, $credentials);
```

While the `'/login'` method is correct, it defeats the purpose of using named routes if you still have to hunt down all the places where you have that URL if/when you decide to change it.